# Let's get critical: Dec 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Buddhism Stack Exchange](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How does one become victim of one's own Karma?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5283/how-does-one-become-victim-of-ones-own-karma)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How does a monk address parents and relatives?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5490/how-does-a-monk-address-parents-and-relatives)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Are Amitabha and Sakyamuni the same?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/amitabha-vs-sakyamuni)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can the noble eightfold path be followed in its entirety by a lay follower?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5455/can-the-noble-eightfold-path-be-followed-in-its-entirety-by-a-lay-follower)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Question about Dana](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5342/question-about-dana)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Anapanasati Buddhist meditation](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5272/anapanasati-buddhist-meditation)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [If Buddha is able to predict the future of other sentient beings how can freewill be possible as its very nature is that of unpredictability?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5448/if-buddha-is-able-to-predict-the-future-of-other-sentient-beings-how-can-freewil)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Did Buddha ever say that educated people would be a problem?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5516/did-buddha-ever-say-that-educated-people-would-be-a-problem)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What was the motivation for the prohibition on eating onions and garlic?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/what-was-the-motivation-for-the-prohibition-on-eating-onions-and-garlic)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Spacious versus Empty](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/5582/spacious-versus-empty)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---